# How do the routers know the complete topology of the network in link state routing?

Tags: networking, routes

I know that in LSR, each router sends LSA packet to its neighbors, which is then flooded. But I can't figure out how the routers know the complete topology in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link state update packets contains information about originating router, its interfaces and neighbors connected via these interfaces, therefore, by collecting and joining this information any router can build graph of the network (or area) to which it belongs.